# How do I remove the inserted a span tag in an href parameter when using Full Calendar and Devel Themer

Tags: views, debugging, javascript

When devel_themer is active inside of a Fullcalendar formated View, links contain the span tag. See below in the href parameter. This however does go away when I disable devel_themer and clear cache.

```
<a unselectable="on" href="/%3Cspan%20thmr%3D%27thmr_73%27%20class%3D%27devel-themer-wrapper%27%3Enode/8%3C/span%3E" class="fc-event fc-event-skin fc-event-hori fc-event-draggable fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-event-default field-performance-dates fc-event-field-field-tic-performance-dates ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; z-index: 8; left: 558.667px; width: 104px; top: 139px; -moz-user-select: none;">
<div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin">
<span class="fc-event-time">11:15</span>
```

You can see in the status (bottom left) that the span tag (with devel_themer generated classes) is in the link.

[image]

This is what the Views Format Settings look like
[image]

And the general Views Admin 
[image]

How might I fix this?

Comment: Fix what? How do you think devel is meant to work without them?

Comment: I'd like to remove the <span> tag inside the href="<span>...". That is the issue.

Comment: But devel is just a development tool, you wouldnt have this running when not developing surely?

Comment: Yes, this is a development instance. However, I'd like to be able to click through a few pages without turning off and on devel_themer. I trust and know why the spans are there to help devel operate. However, I assume that it is not intentional to put <spans> in the <a href>

Comment: Totally agree, however cant imagine the developers for devel could of counted on it working with everything.

Comment: Alex, I completely agree, hence that is why I'm asking on here (SE). Perhaps the collective brain power may even lead to a patch submission. :)

Comment: Ok fair enough, didnt want to get your hopes up thats all ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of little bugs with devel themer. I would just throw a little jquery in one of the js files in the devel_themer module directory to hide any spans in that  tag

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
$('#divnamecontainer a span').remove();
});
```